# Difference between cd and function chdir

Tags: perl, cd, chdir

What is the difference between the `cd` shell command and the Perl function `chdir`? Please can you explain with an example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `cd` command changes the current directory of a shell process; the Perl `chdir` function changes the current directory of a Perl process. They're exactly the same thing, just spelled differently.

Comment: Note that both shell `cd` and Perl `chdir` are implemented in terms of the `chdir(2)` system call.  Modern shell `cd` commands do a good deal of futzing around to pretend that symlinks aren't, but when it is time to change directory, they still use `chdir(2)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't capitalize "perl" because the capitalization is based on the false assertion that "Perl the language" exists independently from "perl the program". In reality the language is whatever the (only) implementation accepts, even if the behavior contradicts the documentation. As they say in the perlfaq: "Q: Is there an ISO or ANSI certified version of Perl? A: Certainly not. Larry expects that he'll be certified before Perl is." I feel uneasy seeing something written in a way I definitely wouldn't have written it, with my name on it.

Comment: @AlanCurry: I disagree with your style choice, but it's your post and you can do as you wish with it.

Comment: The choices are really "Perl" and "`perl`". "perl" makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially both of them do the same thing, but `chdir` is a POSIX system call while `cd` is a normal function used in a program which in this case is the shell.

In practice, `chdir` is called by `cd` to make the change in directory since the program does not have kernel privileges to do it by itself.